# Meaning of その in particular phrases

Tags: usage

I know that phrases like  [Noun A + to と+ sonoその  + Noun B] can be translated as "A and his/her/its B". 
However, when there is no 'to' と, I get a bit puzzled about the meaning. 
For instance, which is the meaning of sono その in the following sentence?

静かな自然、その無の世界と、心で対話するだけでいい。

1) Silent nature (and) ITS world of nothingness  OR Silent nature, the world of nothingness (that is, nature = world of nothingness). 
I am inclined to think that the latter translation is the right one, though I am not sure that nature can be regarded as the world of nothingness in Buddhistic terms... Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

In general, `A、そのB` is a dramatic way of saying `AのB` or `AとそのB`.

> - ミツバチ、その不思議な生態
> - スティーブ・ジョブズ、その波乱万丈の人生
> - 企業のスタートアップ　その理論と実践

That said, I'm not sure how to make sense of the phrase in question. To me, "the world of nothingness *belonging to* the silent nature" and "the world of nothingness *is equal to* the silent nature" seem equally puzzling and vague.

If there is absolutely nothing in the context to explain this phrase, I think I would interpret it along the lines of "the silent nature and its world of nothingness". I don't know if it means something in Buddhism.

Answer (score 0):

と is a preposition linked to 対話:
無の世界と対話する
to talk to a world of emptiness.

その refers to 静かな自然, "quiet nature".

So you use your mind to talk to a world of silence, instead of using sound.